# Inkscape: bucket fill area enclosed by stroke

Tags: inkscape, stroke, fill

I have got a path that encloses small areas within it. I would like to fill each small square below with some color using the bucket fill tool in Inkscape.

However, it always tells me the "area is not bounded" and I can't figure out how to fix that.

[image: stroke-bounded shape]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could duplicate the figure (for security) and then use in the path menu, third section, second command. I'm using a german version, where it is *zerlegen*, from the comments I was informed it is **break apart** as english entry, hotkey Shift-Ctrl-K.

Then you should be able to select a color for the inner parts.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you. It's called "break apart" and then you've got each of the inner squares as separate object then you can then color.

Comment: ALSO: Make sure your Threshold value for the Bucket Fill is set to like 5. I had it at 100 and I think it was trying to fill the entire canvas (unbounded).